# Lights in collection rotate when linked to from another file?

Tags: lighting, linked-data

I've encountered a problem I've never seen before. I have a collection that contains a model and lights (point, spot and area). Looks good, however, when I link to the collection from another file, the model is correct, but the lights are rotated about 100 degrees to the right relative to the model. Why? Blender 3.2, Windows 11

UPDATE: I think it may have something to do with how one or more empties are parented to the lights, but why this should matter when linking is a mystery. All parented empties are included in the linked collection.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: There was legacy animation data in the empty parented to the lights, so when the model was linked to, the destination file had a different position on the timeline so the empty rotated, as programmed. Deleting the animation data from the empty fixed the issue.

Question for admins: Should I leave this post here for reference? Or should I delete it since I solved it myself? Thanks.